# Получение данных из истории браузера средствами JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Нужно получить данные, а именно последние 10 сайтов(url) на которых был пользователь.
history.state маловато, возвращает только текущие данные из вкладки.
(Chrome Ctrl+H)

Comment: Это был бы просто рай для околомаркетологических следящих скриптов.

Comment: Безопастность, понятно!

Comment: Заплатите $100 или ваша история будет отправлена вашим друзьям и родственникам.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению, вы не можете получить последние 10 сайтов(url) на которых был пользователь. Но вы можете сделать так, чтобы пользователь переместился на предыдущую страницу. Подробно можете прочитать здесь: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/History_API